# how to supply a google access token in order to retrieve user spreadsheet list?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets

My app is successfully authorized by a user to use his data. So basically my app has user's access token. Now I need to get the user's spreadsheet list. 
There is an example:

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

    SpreadsheetService service =
        new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

    // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

    // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
    for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
      // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
      System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
  }
}
```

How do I supply an acsess token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this snippet

```
service.setOAuth2Credentials(new Credential(BearerToken
            .authorizationHeaderAccessMethod())
            .setFromTokenResponse(new TokenResponse().setAccessToken(accessToken)));
```

and request scope

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
```

Comment: Please provide the complete example, how to get the accessToken?